# How can I have two or more distinct indexes?

Tags: indexing, subdividing

I often want to have more than one index in a longer LaTeX document. For instance, I might want a general concept index, an index of named persons, and an index of symbolism. How can I have two or more distinct indexes in LaTeX?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [`multind`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/multind.html) package provides simple and straightforward multiple indexing.

You tag each `\makeindex`, `\index` and `\printindex` command with a file name, and indexing commands are written to (or read from) the name with the appropriate (.idx or .ind) extension appended. To create a “general” and an “authors” index, one might write:

```
\usepackage{multind}
\makeindex{general}
\makeindex{authors}
...
\index{authors}{Another Idiot}
...
\index{general}{FAQs}
...
\printindex{general}{General index}
\printindex{authors}{Author index}
```

To complete the job, run LaTeX on your file enough times that labels, etc., are stable, and then execute the commands

```
makeindex general
makeindex authors
```

See also this FAQ: [Multiple indexes](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-multind)

**Update**

`multind` is a package for LaTeX 2.09

Consider the following alternatives:

- [index](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/index?lang=en)
- [splitindex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/splitindex?lang=en)
- [imakeidx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx)
- the *memoir* class has its own multiple-index functionality

Comment: `multind` is not in TeXLive, it seems. Is it obsolete?

Comment: yes, `multind` is a package for LaTeX 2.09

Comment: I tried `index` following one of the answers below and it works perfectly

Answer (score 32):

There is also `imakeidx` designed to provide multiple indexes (has been mentioned in a comment already, but the usage isn't shown)

Just say `\makeindex[name=symbolicname,title={Foo}]` to provide a special index (choose symbolicname appropiately) and `\index[symbolicname]{foo}` to make an index entry to this special index.

The special index is printed with `\printindex[symbolicname]`.

Using `\makeindex`, `\index` and `\printindex` without optional argument will give the usual index as with `makeidx`.

The advantage of `imakeidx` is the automatic call of `makeindex` or `texindy` (if `\write18` is enabled).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeindex[name=person,title={Index of persons}]

\makeindex

\begin{document}

Einstein\index[person]{Einstein}
\blindtext

Heisenberg\index[person]{Heisenberg} % Person index

\blindtext[4]

\index{foo}
\index{bar}
\blindtext

\printindex[person] % Person index
\printindex % usual index

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i'd like to put in a plug for `imakeidx` because it's compatible with the ams document classes, whereas the other packages that support multiple indexes aren't.  it also makes excellent use of the "latex way" of using optional arguments to specify the particular index -- if it's the main index, no option needed, and it names the one index file in the same way as `makeidx`, so completely substitutable there.  this should be the first choice when starting a new project.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Do you refer to a new `amsmath` release (there are plans to do so, I think?)

Comment: there are ongoing discussions about `amsmath`, but nothing that i can quote.  sorry. (as soon as something is definitive, it *will* be announced.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: You't can't quote because it is top-secret or just because the direction is not clear? ;-)

Comment: the direction depends on decisions that haven't been made yet.

Answer (score 12):

One problem with `multind` is that the index heading(s) will not be formatted corresponding to your other chapter (or section) headings but simply with `\Large\bf`.

If you want multiple indexes that respect the general formatting of your document class (and also work with other than the standard classes), use the [`splitidx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/splitindex) package.

Comment: I wouldn't forget **imakeidx**; perhaps because I'm one of the authors. :)

Comment: I have a book with 23 indexes (say again?!) and `splitidx` handles them perfectly. I also recommend the use of `idxlayout`, in case you stumble upon LaTeX [bug 3126](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/3126&introduction=yes&state=open) (it happened to me when using `splitidx` in a book layout, because `\twocolumn` was interfering with `\topskip`). `:-)`

Answer (score 7):

The [`index`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/index) package lets you define additional indexes in addition to the “default” one. (You don't have to use the default one if you don't want to.) This package makes a few other improvements, including making the `\index` command more robust and providing the `\index*` variant to both typeset its argument and add it to the index.

When you use this package, the `\index` and `\printindex` commands take an optional argument which is an internal name for the index. To define a new index, use the `\newindex` command in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{index}
\newindex{person}{pdx}{pnd}{Index of named persons}
\newindex{symbol}{sdx}{snd}{Index of symbolism}

\begin{document}
Hello, \index*[person]{vanden}.

\printindex[person]
\printindex[symbol]
\end{document}
```

The first argument to `\newindex` is the index's internal name which you then pass to `\index` and `\printindex`. The last argument is the title that appears before the index. The second and third argument are the extensions used for the temporary files for the index. For the example above, you'd run makeindex as

```
makeindex -t mydoc.plg -o mydoc.pnd mydoc.pdx
makeindex -t mydoc.slg -o mydoc.snd mydoc.sdx
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new package [manyind](https://ctan.org/pkg/manyind).
It supports multiple indexes. There is just one index file and LaTeX knows how to find the indexes in there. One runs latex and makeindex as if there is just one index. No further programs are required. The user indicates what goes where with commands like \setindex{main}. See the documentation for details of use.
See also the [robustindex](https://ctan.org/pkg/robustindex) package. But all this fails for other alphabets.

Comment: Hi, since you are the maintainer of this package, could you please expand a bit your answer ? You can apply the hyperlink formatting by replacing `{}` by `()`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a completely different approach that doesn't use `\index` but instead uses [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) and [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls). First the terms used in the document are defined in one or more `.bib` files. For example, [`vegetables.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/vegetables.bib) starts with:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@entry{cabbage,
  name={cabbage},
  description={vegetable with thick green or purple leaves},
  identifier={vegetable}
}

@entry{brussels-sprout,
  name={Brussels sprout},
  description={small leafy green vegetable buds},
  identifier={vegetable}
}

@entry{artichoke,
  name={artichoke},
  description={a variety of thistle cultivated as food},
  identifier={vegetable}
}
```

The [`sample-multi2.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/sample-multi2.tex) example file defines a list for each type:

```
\newglossary*{bacteria}{Bacteria}
\newglossary*{markuplanguage}{Markup Languages}
\newglossary*{vegetable}{Vegetables}
\newglossary*{mineral}{Minerals}
\newglossary*{animal}{Animals}
\newglossary*{chemical}{Chemical Formula}
\newglossary*{baseunit}{SI Units}
\newglossary*{measurement}{Measurements}
\newglossary*{film}{Films}
\newglossary*{book}{Books}
\newglossary*{person}{People}
\newglossary*{mediacontrol}{Media Control Symbols}
\newglossary*{information}{Information Symbols}
\newglossary*{weather}{Weather Symbols}
```

The required `.bib` files are identified in the document with `\GlsXtrLoadResources`. The above example file is quite complicated (the result is [`sample-multi2.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/examples/sample-multi2.pdf)), so here's a simplified version that just uses `vegetables.bib`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[
  record,% using bib2gls
  nostyles,stylemods={bookindex},
  nomain,% don't create default 'main' glossary
  index% create index list
 ]{glossaries-extra}

% define custom list:
\newglossary*{vegetable}{Vegetables}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={vegetables},% data in vegetables.bib
  sort={en-GB},% sort by language identified by this locale
  entry-type-aliases={
   entry=dualindexentry% make @entry behave like @dualindexentry
 },
 field-aliases={
   identifier=category % convert identifier field to category field
 },
 type={index},
 dual-type={same as category}
]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Sample}

\Glspl{cabbage} are bigger than \glspl{brussels-sprout}.
An \gls{artichoke} is another type of vegetable.

\printunsrtglossary[type=vegetable,style=tree]
\printunsrtglossary[type=index,style=bookindex]

\end{document}
```

If the document is called `myDoc.tex` then the build process is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls -g myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

First page:

[image: Chapter 1 Sample. Cabbages are bigger than Brussels sprouts. An artichoke is another type of vegetable.]

The list of vegetables doesn't show the locations (page numbers) where the term was used:

[image: Vegetables artichoke a variety of thistle cultivated as food Brussels sprout small leafy green vegetable buds cabbage vegetable with thick green or purple leaves]

The index does show the locations:

[image: Index A artichoke, 1 B Brussels sprout, 1 C cabbage, 1]