# multiple indexing

Tags: indexing, subdividing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I have 2 or more distinct indexes in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-have-2-or-more-distinct-indexes-in-latex)

I would like to have 3 index sections: one for the biological species, second for chemicals and the third for other contents).

The question

1. is should i have a single index with together two as appendix?
2. is it possible to have 3 index categories.

In any case, i would like to have an example file with usage.

Comment: A good start for you would be to look at the [imakeidx](http://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) package manual.

Comment: @ Torbjorn and Donig, Thanks a lot -Anil

Answer (score 4):

The following post has an answer that describes how to use the `multind` package

[How can I have two or more distinct indexes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-have-2-or-more-distinct-indexes-in-latex)

As @egreg mentions in one of his comments, there is also the `imakeidx` package- below is a MWE taken (pretty much) from the documentation (page 6, just before Section 4)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[title=Concept index]
\makeindex[name=persons,title=Index of names,columns=3]

\begin{document}

Here is a list of things and people
\begin{itemize}
 \item \LaTeX \index{latex}
 \item Beccari \index[persons]{beccari}
 \item Gregorio \index[persons]{gregorio}
\end{itemize}

And this is the end of the story.

\printindex

\indexprologue{\small In this index you’ll find only
famous people’s names}
\printindex[persons]

\end{document}
```