# Is it possible to change .ist (index style) file parameters mid-document?

Tags: formatting, indexing, subdividing

Apart from the general document layout, the layout and formatting of indexes depend on two things:

- The parameters of `.ist` (index style) files that are used by `makeindex` when transforming raw index data into `.ind` files (which contain a `theindex` environment). These parameters control, e.g., the presence of letter headings to each index group.
- The definition of the `theindex` environment which is part of document classes and may be changed by packages like [`imakeidx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) and [`idxlayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout). This definition controls, e.g., the number of index columns.

It is possible (although often not sensible from a typographic point of view) to change the definition of the `theindex` environment mid-document (e.g., *"typeset[ting] a general
index in two columns and then switch[ing] to three columns for an index of names"*, `idxlayout` manual, p. 4). But is it possible to change `.ist` (index style) file parameters mid-document (e.g., adding letter headings for groups in some, but not in all indexes)?

EDIT: To clarify: My aim is not to switch `.ist` parameters within a single `theindex` environment, but to use different parameters (or achieve a different formatting) for several indexes within the same document.

EDIT 2: I take Martin Schröder's answer as a hint that it is possible to run `makeindex` "by hand"  several times and to choose different `.ist` files each time. On the other hand, Leo Liu states in a comment that one *"can add TeX boolean switches in the `.ist` format and modify `\index` to make it work"*, i.e., control the formatting through LaTeX macros. I'd be interested in a concrete example of a boolean switch within an `.ist` file.

Comment: I don't think so. But you can add TeX boolean switches in the `.ist` format and modify `\index` to make it work, I think. Can you explain more about what you want?

Comment: And I think it might be useless: index entries are sorted by `makeindex` or `xindy`. Then where is the point the format changes?

Comment: @LeoLiu I added an example (adding letter headings for groups only in some indexes).

Comment: @LeoLiu Can you add an answer that elaborates on TeX boolean switches within an `.ist` file (possibly regarding the presence of letter heads)?

Comment: Well, then you should use `imakeidx` to generate multiple indexes with different options. `imakeidx` supports `\write18` feature to run `makeindex` automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing two different problems. An `.ist` file doesn't influence the final appearance of the index, apart from enabling grouping, for instance. It doesn't have anything to do with the number of columns, which is LaTeX's duty to determine via the definition of `theindex` (that `imakeidx` modifies to have, for instance, a different number of columns than two).

Say you want a main index, typeset in two columns, using the `main.ist` style, and a name index, typeset in three columns, using the `names.ist` style. Then the following declarations will do:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Main Index,columns=2,options=-s main]
\makeindex[name=names,title=Index of Names,colums=3,options=-s names]
```

An entry for the main index will be defined by `\index{tetrapiloctomy}`, while an entry for the name index will be defined by `\index[names]{Doe, John}`.

In general, the `options` key tells `makeindex` or `xindy` what command line options to use (the input and output file names are determined by the package).

In case you have many indices, it's wise to use the `splitindex` option to `imakeidx` (`\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}`), but this requires running LaTeX with the `-shell-escape` option or to run separately `makeindex`.

Comment: Many thanks! I knew that `.ist` files don't influence the number of index columns (and had stated so in my question), but I was not aware of `imakeidx`s `option` key and the possibility to choose `.ist` files this way.

Comment: An `.ist` file controls the final appearance, not only the index grouping, but also the headings, the items, the page number delimiters etc.

Answer (score 6):

It is not true that TeX macros can control the input format which a `.ist` file specifies. It is possible to control some of the output formats by TeX macros. However, it makes no sence in one index.

For multiple indexes, here is an example to use different `.ist` formats:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[
  name=persons,
  title={Names},
  columns=2,
  program=makeindex, % or xindy, texindy
  options={-s mkind.ist},
  noautomatic=false
]
\makeindex[
  name=colors,
  title={Colors},
  columns=1,
  program=makeindex, % or xindy, texindy
  options={-s icase.ist},
  noautomatic=false
]

\begin{document}
Alice\index[persons]{Alice}
Red\index[colors]{Red}
\newpage

Bob\index[persons]{Bob}
Yellow\index[colors]{Yellow}
\newpage

John\index[persons]{John}
Gray\index[colors]{Gray}

\printindex[persons]
\printindex[colors]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create multiple indexes (e.g. with the `index` package) and use different `makeindex` parameters (and different `ist` files) for each.

See also [How can I have two or more distinct indexes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472/5763)