# Multiple indexes in LaTeX

Tags: compiling, indexing, subdividing

I am familiar with the creation of multiple indexes using the `multind` package. One of the required steps is to run the `makeindex` executable for each generated `.idx` file. A typical solution would be do do something along the following lines (this is `unix`; `windows` users look the other way):

```
for file in *.idx; do
    makeindex ${file}
done
```

A disadvantage of this approach is that it may process too many `.idx` files. Is  there an easy way to determine which `.idx` files are really required?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-have-2-or-more-distinct-indexes-in-latex

Comment: @martin Thanks for the link. I want to have a solution where I don't need to know about the names of the index files. They should be detected automatically. Why do you think the link is relevant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a Makefile (or a utility such as `latexmk`, `latexmake`, `latex-make`).

For example, create a `Makefile` file: (`<TAB>` stands for a tabulation character):

```bsh
indexes := $(patsubst %.idx,%.ind,$(wildcard *.idx))
all: $(indexes) # and other stuff
%.ind: %.idx
<TAB>   makeidx $^
```

Then, just issue a `make` command. This can be obviously enhanced, but `make` is really a good starting point.

Comment: Dubac Thanks. I'll have a look at the `Makefile` option. I had tried `latexmk` but that didn't work (unless I did something wrong).

Answer (score 7):

`multind` is *not* the package of choice for multiple indexes: it's almost featureless and too simplistic.  The TeX FAQ entry [Multiple indexes](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-multind) lists some other possibilities

`amsmidx`
`index`
`splitidx`
`imakeidx`

The last one (of which I'm one of the authors) frees you from the problem, as it executes automatically `makeindex`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately, I need the information for `multind`. Does automatically running `makeindex` require enabling `write18`?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen If you have a recent TeX Live (2010 or later) or MiKTeX 2.9, `makeindex` is listed in the allowed programs for the "restricted shell-escape" that's enabled by default.

Comment: Yes, I remember I just read that two days ago:) Funny how easy you (well, I) forget things like this.