# Index for part of document

Tags: macros, indexing

I have a document with hundreds of `\index` entries. I'm trying to generate the index for some part of the document.

The best I could come up with is to disable the `\index` command temporarily. I did it like this:

```
\let\origindex\index
\newcommand\indexoff{\renewcommand\index[2][]{}}
\newcommand\indexon{\let\index\origindex}
```

I use it like this to generate the index of, say, chapter 2 only:

```
\indexoff
\include{chapter1}
\indexon
\include{chapter2}
\indexoff
\include{chapter3}
```

Is there a better or cleaner way? (My experience with this sort of macros is rather limited. I'm not even sure what `\let` does exactly.)

Comment: There would be other syntax choices but that looks OK to me. `\let` defines the new command to have the same definition as the old one so it's like going `\newcommand\origindex{... whatever the definition of \index is ....}`

Comment: related (?) [how-can-i-have-2-or-more-distinct-indexes-in-latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-have-2-or-more-distinct-indexes-in-latex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to do all these changes all over the place, there is in fact a very simple out of the box solution.

As you are using `\include` you can use `\includeonly` to process only some of your included files (and I guess that fits with what you are looking for anyway :-). In that case the `.idx` will only contain index entries from the files that you included, e.g., in your example use

```
\includeonly{chapter2}
```

and you get only the entries from the file `chapter2.tex`. Or if you want chapter2 and 3 use

```
\includeonly{chapter2,chapter3}
```

The `\include` mechanism will save information for cross-references and the TOC but it will not preserve data that goes directly to files other than the `.aux` files. Thus this offers you precisely what you need and the page references will be correct too as long as you use the include mechanism correctly, i.e., all chapters have been compiled or recompiled when earlier chapters got changed.

There are also packages that offer an interactive usage for `\includeonly`, for example, the package `askinclude`.