# babel and index both redefine \markboth and \markright

Tags: packages, indexing, babel

I use both the `index` and `babel` packages. They both redefine `\markboth` and `\markright`. If I include `babel` before `index`, the `index` package warns me about the double redefinition. Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{index}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Extract from the TeX output:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/index/index.sty

LaTeX Warning: Command \markboth  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.


LaTeX Warning: Command \markright  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

) (./a.aux) (./a.aux) )
```

If I swap the two `\usepackage` lines so that `index` is loaded before `babel`, there's no warning. But either way I'm getting the definition of these commands from whichever is loaded last.

My objective is twofold: I want to get rid of the warning (because nonactionable warnings drown out the actionable ones), and I want to understand what I'm losing either way (I haven't spotted any problem so far, but I could be missing something, or run into unexpected problems later as I write more of the document). Presumably, if both packages redefine these commands, they have a good reason.

Should I include `babel` before or after `index`? If before, how do I get rid of the warning?

Is there anything I can/should do to make sure that both `babel` and `index` are working correctly? What problems should I be looking for?

Comment: Do you need `index` at all? If you need multiple indexes, then use `imakeidx`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have macros that rely on `index` that I've been carrying around for years, not just for multiple indices but also `\index*` and possibly other features that I'm not recalling right now. I'd rather not sort them out at this time.  I've never looked at `imakeidx`. (Could you add an answer mentioning it [to this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-have-two-or-more-distinct-indexes)?)

Comment: Done so ;-) I wonder, it has not been given as an answer (but as comment only, not showing how to use it)

Comment: if the language of your document is not english, then the substitutions of `babel` for common heading strings are what you'll probably want.  i haven't looked, but i suspect that "Index" is the only option you'll get with the `index` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Edit 2023

In the meantime the LaTeX kernel has changed the `\markboth` and `\markright` command (to support extended mark options). That means that the check from index.sty fails regarding in any case, with and without babel and also regardless of the loading order.

The warning can not be avoid unless the package is adapted.

### Old answer

Load `index` before `babel` you then will get both: the redefinition from `index` and the language additions from `babel` as babel will store the definition in `\org@markboth` and then use it.

Comment: With `index` loaded FIRST, I've switched from `babel` to `polyglossia`  (along with my ongoing conversion from `pdflatex` to `lualatex`). However, I'm still seeing the warnings: "LaTeX Warning: Command \markboth  has changed. Check if current package is valid." and "Command \markright  has changed. Check if current package is valid." Do I need to just accept that these warnings will continue, despite the `index` > `polyglossia` order? Thanks in advance!

Comment: why switching to polyglossia? babel works fine with lualatex (and in various part actually better than polyglossia).

Comment: I've read somewhere that `polyglossia` works better with `lualatex`, but it really doesn't matter to me as long as I get the same functionality. The issue is that I get the identical warnings whether I use `babel` OR `polyglossia` immediately after loading `index`. Neither `babel` NOR `polyglossia` prevent the warnings from appearing. What am I missing?? Thank you!!

Comment: @RosesBouquet I added an edit. You could try to contact the author (the readme on ctan contains a mail address), but with such an old sty it could be difficult to get an update.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with your assessment. Your edit will help those unfortunates like me who continue to search for answers that otherwise don't exist. I sometimes keep poking at the issue hoping that something will have changed. I'll try to contact the `index` author just the same. Thanks again!!

Comment: The `index` Author appears to be `David M. Jones`, but I don't see an email for DMJ in the package documentation. I'll continue to look. Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: @RosesBouquet as I wrote there is an email in the readme https://www.ctan.org/pkg/index

Comment: Email sent. Thank you!