# Record multiple indexes in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, subdividing, tocbibind

I have a document with multiple indexes. All of the indexes should be mentioned in the table of contents (as well as similar elements such as the bibliography). I use the `index` package to define alternative indexes and the `tocbibind` package to list them in the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\newindex{other}{odx}{ond}{Other index}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\index{foo}
\index[other]{bar}
This page is intentionally not left blank.
\printindex
\printindex[other]
\end{document}
```

I'd expect the second index to be called “Other Index”, but both the title on the last page and the corresponding entry in the table of contents read “Index” instead. This is the fault of the `tocbibind` package: without it, the title appearing on the last page is correct — but of course the indexes aren't listed in the table of content.

This is kind of mentioned in the `tocbibind` documentation:

> the heading text is picked up from the `\indexname` [command]. The heading texts can be changed by changing the standard commands, or by using `\setindexname{name}` […]

Ok, but how do I do this for multiple indexes with different titles?

I'd prefer to stick to `index`, but I'll switch to [an alternative](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-have-two-or-more-distinct-indexes) if I really need to. However the problem seems to be in `tocbibind`. Is there an alternative for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `tocbinind` package and the `index` package both redefine the `theindex` environment, so whichever gets loaded last destroys the customizations made by the other one.

The `tocbibind` package does some relatively complex analysis to determine which kind of section heading to insert. The `index` package adds two simple things: it redefines `\indexname` according to the first optional argument to `\printindex`, and it adds a prologue below the section or chapter title. So I'll load `index` first, then `tocbibind`, and then patch in the functionality from the `index` package.

```
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
% Patch the functionality from the index package into the {theindex}
% environment, where it was overridden by the tocbibind package. Note that
% this assumes that index was loaded first, then tocbibind.
\let\theindex@beforeindex\theindex
\def\theindex{%
  \edef\indexname{\the\@nameuse{idxtitle@\@indextype}}%
  \let\@topnewpage@real\@topnewpage
  \def\@topnewpage[##1]{\@topnewpage@real[##1%
      \ifx\index@prologue\@empty\else%
        \index@prologue%
        \bigskip%
      \fi%
    ]%
    \let\@topnewpage\@topnewpage@real%
  }%
  \theindex@beforeindex%
}
```

For just the multiple index feature of `index`, and not the prologue feature, the redefinition would be a lot simpler:

```
\let\theindex@beforeindex\theindex
\def\theindex{%
  \edef\indexname{\the\@nameuse{idxtitle@\@indextype}}%
  \theindex@beforeindex%
}
```

or

```
\def\index@redefine@indexname{\edef\indexname{\the\@nameuse{idxtitle@\@indextype}}}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\theindex\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\index@redefine@indexname%
  \theindex@beforeindex%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this what you want? For a quick setup, using `\setindexname{Other Index}` is perhaps the easiest way to achieve this.

`index` is an old package and most likely the authors of `tocbibind` hadn't this package in mind when they developed `tocbibind`.

Another possibility would be `imakeidx`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\newindex{other}{odx}{ond}{Other index}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\index{foo}
\index[other]{bar}
This page is intentionally not left blank.
\printindex
\setindexname{Other index}
\printindex[other]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather keep the nastiness in the preamble (actually I'm stuffing it into a local package) and keep the documents clean. The document-side solution also doesn't work for the index package's prologue feature (which admittedly I'm not using right now).