# Creating multiple indices with customizable options

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I want to create multiple indices with two columns and no clear page in between.

I tried the splitidx package, which does not give me the same options as imakeidx, which in turn gives me an "misplaced \printindex[Hal]" in the following MWE:

```
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=2, name=As, title=As]
\makeindex[columns=2, name=Bs, title=Bs]
\indexsetup{noclearpage}
\begin{document}

\section{A}
Eintrag A\index[Hal]
\newpage
\section{B}
Eintrag B\index[Alka]
\newpage
\printindex[Hal]


\end{document}
```

my question is, is there a way to customize the splitidx the same way as the imakeidx? is there a solution for my problem with imakeidx, or is there a alternate package(which is compatible with hyperref) I can use and if how?

Comment: The `glossaries` package might be interesting. More alternatives can be found here: [How can I have two or more distinct indexes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472/134144)

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not a MWE because it can't be compiled. Besides this your syntax is wrong: The optional arguments of `\index` and `\printindex` describe the index not the entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=2, name=As, title=As]
\makeindex[columns=2, name=Bs, title=Bs]
\indexsetup{noclearpage}
\begin{document}

\section{A}
Eintrag A\index[As]{Hal} \index[Bs]{Blka}
\newpage
\section{B}
Eintrag B\index[As]{Bal} \index[Bs]{Alka}
\newpage
\printindex[As]

\printindex[Bs]

\end{document}
```

[image]