# executing makeindex command in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, makeindex

I am writing a book using the Springer SVM monograph class. I want to create multiple indexes, and have found a few resources:
[How can I have two or more distinct indexes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472/how-can-i-have-two-or-more-distinct-indexes)
http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-multind

...and others

At the end of each of these descriptions it says to "execute the following commands"
'''makeindex myfile
makeindex myfile.adx -o myfile.and'''

My issue is that I am using Overleaf to collaborate with my coauthors. I'm not sure how to "execute commands" in Overleaf, and thus cant seem to make these options work.  How do I execute  commands in Overleaf?

A small use case can be found here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/wgrfqbmkrmwv

Compiling in overleaf gives one index (the one containing FAQs}, but not two.

Comment: overleaf uses latexmk so it usually detects this and runs makeindex on its own, although you could ad a latexmkrc file to configure things more if you need finer control

Comment: when I recompile the second index doesnt appear. I have
\usepackage{index}
...
\makeindex  
\newindex{aut}{adx}{and}{Name Index}
....
then in the body of a chapter I have:
\index[aut]{Another Idiot}
\index{FAQs}
...
then back in the main.tex file, after all of the "include" statements I have:

\printindex
\printindex[aut]

only the first index shows.

Comment: sorry, I'm a complete noobie here. How do I provide a small document?

Comment: I see you figured it out (but three back ticks not three apostrophe to mark a code block, I fixed)

Comment: mm if you look in the log you will see `Latexmk: Index file 'dd820.adx' written
  ==> but it has an extension I do not know how to handle <==
`  that must be fixable..

Answer (score 1):

If you use an example from the latexmk manual saved as `latexmkrc` then latexmk knows about adx files and builds your document

```
add_cus_dep( 'adx', 'and', 0, 'ndx2nnd' );
sub ndx2nnd {return system( "makeindex -o \"$_[0].and\" \"$_[0].adx\"" );}
push @generated_exts, 'adx', 'and';
```

[image]

The above was done locally but here is a project on overleaf

https://www.overleaf.com/read/wxdpbbstkypb

Comment: This works really well for the use case I gave, however I'm struggling to use it for the document class "svmono". I am linking an Overleaf file in the original question and here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/wgrfqbmkrmwv